# How to select table id within a div or two?

Tags: jquery, html, html-table, tablesorter

I'm trying to select the following table id - myTable - which is nested within a few divs.

Here is a screenshot of the element panel from Chrome:

[image]

I've tried using the below to no avail:

```
    $('#myTable').tablesorter();
    $('table#myTable').tablesorter();
```

```
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <title>Beverly Bonus Dashboard</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery/js/jquery-min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery/js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery/tablesorter/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/central.js"></script>
        <link type="text/css" href="../js/jquery/css/tpurple/jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
      </head>
      <? if ($isDelegate == "true") { ?>
      <body>
        <div id="tabs">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-3">Administration</a></li>
          </ul>
          <div id="tabs-1">
            <p>Tab 1 content</p>
          </div>
          <div id="tabs-2">
            <p>Tab 2 content</p>
          </div>
          <div id="tabs-3">
            <button id="button_showUsers" value="<?=$centreID; ?>">Show Users</button>
            <button id="button_addUsers" value="<?=$centreID; ?>">Add Users</button>
            <button id="button_removeUsers">Remove Users</button>       
            <br>
            <div id="users"></div>               
          </div>
        </div>   
      </body>
      <? }//end if isDelegate 
      else {
        echo $fullName .", You do not have permission to view this page";
      }
      ?>  
    </html>
```

file: central.js

```
<pre>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      //Tabs
      $('#tabs').tabs({ spinner: 'Retrieving data...' });
      //Buttons
      $("button").button();     
      //Dialog Box 
      $('#dialog').dialog()
      //error messages
      var $error_1 = $('<div></div>')
        .html("You Do Not Have Permission To View This Site.")
        .dialog({autoOpen: false, title: 'Error'});  
       $('#myTable.tablesorter').tablesorter();

      //site stuff
      $("#button_showUsers").click(function(){
        //get the centre id
        var ID = $(this).val();
        //echo out the delegates based on the centre ID
        $.getJSON("../php/show_delegates.php", {  centreID: ID }, function(data) { 
          $("#users").html("");
          var tbl ="<table id='myTable' class='tablesorter'><thead><tr><td>AGS</td><td>Name</td><td>Centre ID</td><td>Start Date</td><td>End Date</td></tr></thead><tbody>";
          $.each(data.delegates, function(key, val) {
            tbl = tbl 
            +"<tr>"
            +"<td>"+val.ags+"</td>"
            +"<td>"+val.full_name+"</td>"
            +"<td>"+val.centre_id+"</td>" 
            +"<td>"+val.start_date+"</td>"
            +"<td>"+val.end_date+"</td>"
            +"</tr>";
          });//end each
          tbl = tbl
          +"</tbody></table>";   
        $("#users").append(tbl);
        })//end getJSON 
      }); //button_showUsers

      $("#button_addUsers").click(function(){
        //get the centre id
        var ID = $(this).val();  
        $("#users").html("");
        var tbl ="<table id='myTable' class='tablesorter'><thead><tr><td>AGS</td><td>Name</td><td>Centre ID</td><td>Start Date</td><td>End Date</td></tr></thead><tbody>"
        +"<tr>"
        +"<td><input type=text id='ags'maxlength='8'></input></td>"
        +"<td></td>"
        +"<td></td>"
        +"<td></td>"        
        +"<td></td>"    
        +"</tr></tbody></table>";   
        $("#users").append(tbl);
      }); //button_addUsers

      //log user out when window closes
      $(window).unload( function () { 
         $.get("../php/logout.php", function(data) { }); 
         alert("Bye now!");
      });//end unload

        //log user out when window closes
      $(window).load( function () { 
        $.get("../php/user_details.php", function(data) { }); 
         //alert("Bye now!");
      });//end unload


    }); //end (document).ready
```

Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: any errors? please post everything we need to know to help debugging.

Comment: make sure the ids are identical and you have no other id as `myTable`, write the code in `.ready` handler or at the end of the page

Comment: better if you can show some code !

Comment: since there's little to go on here, I'm going to go ahead and ask the obvious question... is your jQuery linked properly? Otherwise you'd succesfully select the div, even if you have multiple div's with that id.  (You'd just select them all)

Comment: Thank you all for the responses.  I'm trying to work out how to post my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work.

1. May be you have initiated the call $('#myTable') before the html is loaded. Try to initialize the tablesorter in document.ready()
2. The html you shown is loaded to the page later using a ajax call. In that case you need to initialize the tablesorter after the ajax call.
3. Or you got an element with same id some where before in html and thus it fails. Try $('#myTable') in console and check if its returning the correct element.

Comment: Hey Jithin, I tried $('#myTable') in console and it returned the following: http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8425/7499178020_2ebc9590c4_z.jpg

Comment: And you are getting the correct table using the selector. right?

Comment: Yes, its point 2. Executing the $('#myTable.tablesorter').tablesorter(); before the ajax call won't work as the table is not loaded yet. You have to cut it from there and paste it after $("#users").append(tbl);

Comment: Place the $('#myTable.tablesorter').tablesorter(); after $("#users").append(tbl);. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following:

```
$('#myTable.tablesorter').tablesorter();
```

or

```
$('#myTable .tablesorter').tablesorter();
```

Comment: `tablesorter()` is a method not a `class` selector.

Comment: @undefined according to the screen shot the OP supplied it is also a class for that table. I have changed my code to add the method to clarify this.

Answer (score 0):

1) Keep your Html as it is.

2) Include Latest Jquery, Jquery UI and jquery.tablesorter.js java script files as well as also include Jquery UI Style sheet.

3) Replace Following Javascript / JQuery:

```
function appendUserTable() {
            $("#users").html("");
            var strdata = "[{'ags':25,'full_name':'User1','central_id':1,'start_date':'01-01-2001','end_date':'12-31-2005'},{'ags':20,'full_name':'User2','central_id':2,'start_date':'05-01-2002','end_date':'12-31-2007'},{'ags':22,'full_name':'User3','central_id':3,'start_date':'06-05-2003','end_date':'12-31-2010'}]";
            var tbl = "<table id='myTable' class='tablesorter'><thead><tr><th>AGS</th><th>Name</th><th>Centre ID</th><th>Start Date</th><th>End Date</th></tr></thead><tbody>";
            var dataObject = eval('(' + strdata + ')');
            for (i in dataObject) {
                tbl = tbl + "<tr>" + "<td>" + dataObject[i]["ags"] + "</td>" + "<td>" + dataObject[i]["full_name"] + "</td>" + "<td>" + dataObject[i]["central_id"] + "</td>" + "<td>" + dataObject[i]["start_date"] + "</td>" + "<td>" + dataObject[i]["end_date"] + "</td>" + "</tr>";
            }
            tbl = tbl + "</tbody></table>";
            $("#users").append(tbl);

            if ($("#users").find("#myTable").length > 0) {
                $("#myTable").tablesorter();
            }
        }

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#tabs").tabs();
            //if Show User Button Clicked
            $("#tabs-3 #button_showUsers").click(function() {
                //get the centre id
                // var ID = $(this).val();  
                //Append User Table Sorter
                appendUserTable();
            });
            //if Add User Button Clicked
            $("#tabs-3 #button_addUsers").click(function() {
                //get the centre id
                // var ID = $(this).val();  
                //Append User Table Sorter
                appendUserTable();
            });
            //Place other Login/Logout Script Here...
        }); //End of document ready
```

4) Add Following CSS For Sortable Table

```
table.tablesorter {
  background-color: #CDCDCD;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 8pt;
  margin: 10px 0 15px;
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
}
table.tablesorter thead tr .header {
  background-image: url("http://tablesorter.com/themes/blue/bg.gif");
  background-position: right center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  cursor: pointer;
}
table.tablesorter thead tr th, table.tablesorter tfoot tr th {
  background-color: #E6EEEE;
  border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 8pt;
  padding: 4px;
}
table.tablesorter {
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 8pt;
  text-align: left;
}
```

Try this on codebins too. http://codebins.com/codes/home/4ldqpbr